# Is there a way to make ngModel recognize property binding syntax?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I just stumbled into the painful discovery that if you're binding values to your input's attributes `ngModel` doesn't recognize them, most visible with the error it throws about needing a `name` attribute or set the `ngModelOptions` to `standalone`.  I came across a page on github addressing this issue but the comments stopped back in 2016.  Their solution so far is to make the input standalone and it will be excluded from the overall form, which isn't what I want to do.  As far as I know `[attr.name]="..." [attr.id]="..."` is the only way to bind property values.

For Angular to be what it is as a platform you wouldn't expect something like property binding to stop your entire workflow and require some advanced miracle.  It seems like if we want to do anything beyond having a simple predefined form where people can put in their name, address and super power we have to go with something else in the real world.  Why not have more documentation outlining the current limitations of the FormsModules because I'm sure lots of people who get use to working with the things that make Angular ANGULAR by default have much higher expectations of the FormsModules than what they can actually live up to.  Is there any resolution or current info on any progress with this issue?

Comment: You may want to consider re-wording your question;  As it stands now, you are describing a theoretical issue which is very difficult to understand without seeing the code you are trying to work with, and the second half of the question comes off as a rant in disguise.  You would have a much greater chance of getting a good answer if you were to show some sample code, and cut down the commentary.

Comment: `[attr.name]` is the way to bind to attributes as `attr` suggests, `[name]` is the syntax to bind to properties.

Answer (score 0):

Binding to `ngModel` is only supported for components that implement `ControlValueAccessor`.

To bind to custom properties use

```
@Input()
myProp:string;

@Output()
myPropChange:EventEmitter<String> = new EventEmitter<String>();
```

The naming convention `foo` (input) and `fooChange` (output) is required to support two-way binding like

```
[(myProp)]="bar"
```

If this naming is not followed, only explicit binding to both is supported

```
[myProp]="bar" (myPropX)="bar = $event"
```

for

```
@Input()
myProp:string;

@Output()
myPropX:EventEmitter<String> = new EventEmitter<String>();
```